# Fetch a functions parameters that may include multiple functions as parameters

Tags: regex, string, state-machine, string-parsing

I'm trying to parse a string representation of a function call to fetch its parameters. These parameters may be a primitive value such as `1` or `x` but they may also be a function call such as `add(x, 1)` or a function of function call like `add(add(20, x), y)`.

Every argument is separated by comma and a space like F(arg1, arg2, arg3...)

How can I fetch the arguments in this scenario? Is it possible to do it with regex?

I expect the output of the string `mul(add(x, 0), 1)` be `['add(x, 0)', '1']`

Note that the functions arity is variable, and so is the function calls that an argument does.

Other example:

`evaluate(add(x, sub(1, y)), sub(mul(parse(200), 3), x), 2, 4)` should return `['add(x, sub(1, y))', 'sub(mul(parse(200), 3), x)', '2', '4']`

Comment: Parsing recursive structures is difficult with regular expressions. Use a recursive descent parser.

Comment: @Barmar What is it? Can you provide an example in Python or something?

Comment: It's not something you can write a simple solution to.

Comment: It's a chapter in a compiler textbook.

Comment: @Barmar Oh I see.. thanks, I'll look it up